# null check operator error while using getx in flutter

Tags: flutter

While creating a simple demo of getx, I am getting an error 'null check operator is used on a null value'

I am using GetBuilder

here is my code

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Getx With Hive'),),
      body:GetBuilder<TransactionController>(builder: (controller) {

        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: controller.transactions.length,
            itemBuilder: (context,index){
              return Text('hello');
        });
      },),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: (){},
        child: Text('+'),
      ),

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like that error is in that piece of code. Because the error indicates that you are using `!` on a null variable, but the code you show doesn't have `!` anywhere. Perhaps in the `TransactionController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just you need to initialize your controller to init properties
add this line in your code `init: TransactionController(),`

```
GetBuilder<TransactionController>(
  init: TransactionController(),
  builder: (controller) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: controller.transactions.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Text('hello');
        });
  },
),
```